# Stack Masked View to Make Curved Card React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Anyone know how to make card like this using view only?
[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10mEq.png)

Currently I'm still using SVG combined with view, but I'm curious if this result can be achieved using view only method.

I've searching about masked-view in react native using this library
https://github.com/react-native-masked-view/masked-view
but I have a gradle issue when I'm trying to build the app.

And apparently this issue hasn't solved yet.
https://github.com/react-native-masked-view/masked-view/issues/89

Current Result using SVG
[current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMoKG.png)

Component :

```js
<View style={styles.card}>
            <Image
              source={{
                uri:
                  'https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/flat-cityscape-with-blue-sky-white-clouds-and-sun-modern-city-skyline-vector-id931139544?s=612x612',
              }}
              style={[
                styles.cardImage,
                {
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  marginTop: 0,
                  resizeMode: 'cover',
                },
              ]}
            />
            {/* <View style={[styles.cardImage, {}]} /> */}
            <View
              style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                bottom: 60,
              }}>
              <SvgExclude color={'#FFF'} />
            </View>
            <View style={[styles.cardDescription, {}]}>
              <Text>
                  Kota Indonesia dan Keunikannya
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
```

Style :

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  card: {
    marginTop: 16,
    width: windowWidth - 32,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    height: 179,
    borderRadius: 16,
    elevation: 2,
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
  cardImage: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 134,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
  },
  cardDescription: {
    height: 60,
    width: windowWidth - 32,
    borderBottomEndRadius: 16,
    borderBottomStartRadius: 16,
    borderTopEndRadius: 16,
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    padding: 12,
  },
});
```

SVG :

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import Svg, {Path} from 'react-native-svg';

function SvgExclude(props) {
  return (
    <Svg
      width={16}
      height={16}
      fill="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      {...props}>
      <Path
        fillRule="evenodd"
        clipRule="evenodd"
        d="M0 0c0 8.837 7.163 16 16 16H0V0z"
        fill={props.color}
      />
    </Svg>
  );
}

export default SvgExclude;
```

Thankyou..

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on snack please have a look at it. I'm using View only for this design.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{
      alignSelf:'center',
      marginTop:100
      width:300,
      height:250,
      backgroundColor:'red',
      shadowColor: "#000",
      shadowOffset: {
        width: 0,
        height: 2,
      },
      shadowOpacity: 0.25,
      shadowRadius: 3.84,
      elevation: 5,
      borderRadius:10
    }}>
      <View style={{
        position:'absolute',
        bottom:0,
        height:100,
        width:'100%',
        backgroundColor:'white',
        shadowColor: "#000",
        shadowOffset: {
          width: 0,
          height: 10,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.5,
        shadowRadius: 13.84,
        elevation: 10,
        borderBottomLeftRadius:10,
        borderBottomRightRadius:10,
        borderTopRightRadius:10,
        }}>
          <View style={{
            position:'abolute',
            backgroundColor:'red',
            top:0,
            width:'100%',
            height:20,
            borderBottomLeftRadius:20
            }}>
            </View>
        </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

[image]